# Renaming files from *_pattern_* to *.pattern

Tags: unix, file-rename

I want to replace a file `abcd.dfkk_kjjsd_20140313_2341` to `abcd.dfkk_kjjsd.20140313`

I am using the below command.

```
ls "abcd.dfkk_kjjsd_20140313_2341" | awk -F_ '{$(NF)="";}1' OFS=_  |
sed 's/\(.*\)_/\1/' |
sed 's/\(.*\)_/\1./' | awk '{print("mv "$1" "$1)}' | /bin/ksh
```

Please suggest a better way to achieve this.

`*_20140313_*` should be renamed to `*.20140313`

Comment: Check this link: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/search/label/rename

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rename` command,

```
rename 's/^(.*)_[^_]*$/$1/' *20140313*
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```
rename 's/(_(\d+)_)\d+$/.$2/' *20140313*
```

The first argument to `rename` is a Perl expression.